# Typescript - dynamic multidimensional objects array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an API that returns dynamic data, in form of an array of objects with changing structure. The objects can have any data type (string, number, null).
So it can be like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Address": "0x964fd5383dfdbfbd54224de9f773e5ac7bdb0086",
            "Number of Doses": 58,
            "Rank": 1
        },
        {
            "Address": "0x062f95282a797c49f0994699c2c96ae566293e0c",
            "Number of Doses": 53,
            "Rank": 2
        },
....
    ]
}
```

or like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Type": 1,
            "Change": "true",
            "Name": "abc",
            "Version": 1
        },
        {
            "Type": 2,
            "Change": "false",
            "Name": "xyz",
            "Version": 2
        },
....
    ]
}
```

I'm getting this in Typescript and I need to convert it into an array of all values plus the headers (it gets dumped into a sheet).

So the first example should translate to:

[image]

while the second one to:

[image]

How can I achieve this in Typescript?

Update:
I managed to do it in JavaScript, with the below code, which doesn't work in TS (should I mention that I have zero experience with TS?).

```
let response = [];
let data = result.value["data"]; //data from API
//get the first element in array and extract its items -> the number of columns and the headers
const firstDataElement = data[0];
const keys = Object.keys(firstDataElement);
response = makeArray(data.length + 1, keys.length, undefined); //+1 because we add the columns headers

//add columns headers
for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
    response[0][k] = keys[k];
}

//loop through all elements in data array
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //skip first element of response, we already have columns headers in there
    const item = data[i];
    let values = Object.values(item);
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      let value = values[j];
      response[i + 1][j] = value;
    }
}
return response;



function makeArray(w, h, val) {
  var arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    arr[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < h; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = val;
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: there's no built-in function that does exactly that, so you gonna write some code for this.

Comment: Isn't this just JSON -> CSV?